# Adding filtering, searching and pagination to realtime streaming table

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

I have a table that updates using data served by node in realtime. The table is rendered using d3.js.

My problem is that I don't know how to add filtering, searching and pagination capabilities to the table using d3.js. I'm a begginer and having trouble understanding where would be the best place to put the code. I've been thinking about using an external library to do it but it's better and cleaner if I find a way to just do it with d3.js.

This is my code:

```
var table = d3.select('#data')

table.append('thead')
    .append('tr')
    .selectAll('th')
        .data(['Title', 'Visits', 'Sales', 'Conversion(%)'])
    .enter()
        .append('th')
        .text(function (d) { return d })

table.append('tbody')

function setupData(data) {
    var rows = d3.select('tbody')
        .selectAll('tr')
        .data(data, function(d) { return d.title })

    var entertd = rows.enter()
        .append('tr')
            .selectAll('td')
                .data(function(d) { return d3.map(d).values() })
            .enter()
                .append('td')

    entertd.append('div')
    entertd.append('span')

    var td = rows.selectAll('td')
        .data(function(d) { return d3.map(d).entries() })
        .attr('class', function (d) { return d.key })

    td.select('div')
        .transition()
        .duration(800)
        .style('width', function(d) {
            switch (d.key) {
                case 'conversion_rate' :
                    // percentage scale is static
                    scale = d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([0, 1])
                        .range([0, 100])
                    break;
                case 'today_visits': 
                case 'sold_today' :
                    scale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d1) { return d1[d.key] }))
                    .range([0, 100])
                    break;
                default:
                    return '0px'
            }
            return scale(d.value) + 'px'
        })
    td.select('span')
        .text(function(d) {
            if (d.key == 'conversion_rate') {
                return Math.round(100*d.value).toFixed(2) + '%';
            }
            return d.value
        })
}


var socket = io();

//var data = [];
socket.on('sellers-'.concat(<%= seller %>), function(msg){
    var data = [];
    var seller = $.parseJSON(msg);
    var items = seller['items'];
    for(item in items) {
        var item_data = items[item];
        data.push({'title': item_data['title'], 'today_visits': item_data['today_visits'], 'sold_today': item_data['sold_today'], 'conversion_rate': item_data['conversion_rate']});
    }
    setupData(data);
    //setupData(JSON.parse(msg).items)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your main D3 chart render method is already set up to use the [General Update Pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218), so you should be good to go there.

You're best bet with filtering and searching is probably just using a native JavaScript solution.  Just call your `setupData` method with the filtered data set, and the chart will update.  For instance:

```
var allData;

var loadItems = function(items) {
    var item;

    allData = [];
    for (item in items) {
        allData.push(item);
    }
}

var filterMatching = function(matcher) {
    var item;
    var filteredData = [];
    for (item in allData) {
        if (matcher(item)) filteredData.push(item);
    }
    setupData(filteredData);
}

// filter on conversion rate
filterMatching(function(item) { return item.conversion_rate > 0.5; });

// search on title
filterMatching(function(item) { return /foobar/.test(item); });
```

Pagination is a little bit trickier, but still pretty straightforward.  You just need to do a little math.

```
var itemsPerPage = 10;

var numberOfPages() {
    return Math.ceil(allData.length / itemsPerPage);
}

var goToPage(pageNumber) {
    var firstIndex = (pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage;
    var pageItems = allData.slice(firstIndex, firstIndex + itemsPerPage);

    setupData(pageItems);
}
```

Now getting those to work together nicely may take a bit of effort.

Alternatively, you could look into applying a library like [Crossfilter](https://square.github.io/crossfilter/), which plays nicely with D3.  Your filtering and pagination might look something like this in Crossfilter:

```
var filter = crossfilter(records);

var conversion_rate = filter.dimension(function(d) { return d.conversion_rate; });
var title = filter.dimension(function(d) { return d.title; });

// filter on a dimension
conversion_rate.filterRange([0.5, 1]);
title.filterFunction(function (d) { return /foobar/.test(d); });

// take the top x of a dimension
conversion.group().top(5);
```

If you have a lot of data to filter than using Crossfilter will be much faster.  However, since you're charting all the data at the start anyway, it doesn't seem like you have all that much, so hand-rolling it with native JavaScript might be the way to go.